# global variable empty if function is called using variable

Tags: php, function, variables

Why this doesn't work

```
$(document).on('click', '.title', function(){
    let fn = 'abc';
    $.post('common.php', {fn}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

**common.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['fn'])) {$_POST['fn']();}

$cols = '323';

function abc() {
    global $db;  // this works (db connection);
    global $cols;
    echo $cols;  //  doesn't work result is empty
    echo '323';  // this works
}
```

There is no logic - some global variables work (for example `$db` connection) and some don't work.

Any help?

Comment: It work in https://3v4l.org/p630p But you should use `;` after `$db`

Comment: @Mohammad, that's not my question. Pls read the title - `if function is called using variable`. Call `abc()` using `if (isset($_POST['fn'])) {$_POST['fn']();}` Typo corrected.

Comment: Because when you calling function in first line, `$cols` doesn't defined. But if you define variable before function call, it work correctly. https://3v4l.org/8cUNj

Comment: it's working here [link](https://3v4l.org/ToNBm) . are you sure that your function is executed? make sure that your ```isset($_POST['fn'])``` is true.

Comment: @Mohammad, excellent, thanks a lot. Pls place as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you calling function in first line

```
if (isset($_POST['fn'])) {$_POST['fn']();}
```

`$cols` variable doesn't defined. But if you define variable before function call, it work correctly.

```
$cols = '323';
if (isset($_POST['fn'])) {$_POST['fn']();}

function abc() {...
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/8cUNj)